# dynamically add or remove objects in an asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, object, view

I have (for example) these two objects:

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Order> Orders;
}

class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I want one View on which you can edit the Customer data
(that part is already working fine), but I want some kind of
'dynamic grid' to add/remove/update orders on the same page.

How can you do this? With jQuery you can add or remove html controls, but to add or remove
an Order object with it?
Any ideas?

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you checking out the following [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) from Steve Sanderson which illustrates a nice technique which could be used for editing a variable length list in ASP.NET MVC 2.